# A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

//constructor which i have initialised before only.

```
const [groupChatName, setGroupChatName] = useState();
```

// updated part where values is showing that it is undefined and it is changing from uncontrolled to controlled

```
<FormControl d="flex">
          <Input
            placeholder="Group Name"
            mb={3}
            value={groupChatName}
            onChange={(e) => setGroupChatName(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Button
            variant="solid"
            colorScheme="teal"
            ml={1}
            isLoading={renameloading}
            onClick={handleRename}
          >
            Update
          </Button>
        </FormControl>
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `defaultValue={groupChatName}` attribute instead of the `value` attribute.
You can reference the docs here...[uncontrolled-components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `undefined` to the value prop in the `Input` component and then changing it to string on change.

Provide a initial value in `useState`

```
const [groupChatName, setGroupChatName] = useState("");
```

Comment: Thank you , i tried this also and its solved my error